# How to play a 20ms audio file in Android Studio using a for loop?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a binary string and I want to play two sounds based on the type of bit. I have put a `1200hz` WAV file and `1600hz` WAV file in the `raw folder`.

Now I want to iterate through this binary string, and if the bit is `zero`, I want to play `1200hz` wav file and if the bit is `one`, then I want to play `1600hz` wav file. Each of this wav file is `20 milliseconds in length`.

For example, if the 3rd character in the binary string is zero, then I want to play the `1200hz` frequency wav file for 20ms, and then head to the next character, i.e., the 4th character and play it's respective sound.

However, my code is not working like I wanted it to. I'm new to android studio and I don't know how to resolve it. Please help me.

Here's my code

```
    private void playTone(){
        String bin_string = "011100101010111010101011101000";

        final MediaPlayer f1200 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wave1200hz);
        final MediaPlayer f1600 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wave1600hz);

        for(int i=0; i<bin_string.length(); i++){
            if(bin_string.charAt(i)=='0'){
                //play 1200hz
                f1200.start();
            }
            if(bin_string.charAt(i)=='1'){
                //play 1600hz
                f1600.start();
            }
        }

        f1200.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            }
        });

        f1600.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: ok, will edit it now

Comment: Your for loop will have ended before even one sound has finished. You should only start the next sound if a sound has finished. So in onCompletion() i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iteration is not correct. You should proceed to next char inside onCompletion. The approximate way to do it as follows:

Make an int counter as global field.
Than method next() that does the following

```
public void next(){
    if(bin_string.charAt(counter)=='0'){
                    //play 1200hz
                    f1200.start();
                }
                if(bin_string.charAt(counter)=='1'){
                    //play 1600hz
                    f1600.start();
                }
}
```

Than inside the oncompletion add

```
counter++;
if (counter< bin_string.length){
next();
} else {
mp.release();
counter=0;
}
```

Also you should remember to release the second mediaplayer.

Comment: It's showing this error `cannot resolve method next()`

Comment: did you add the next() method?

Comment: I copied the exact code you answered into the eventlistener section and I'm getting that error

Comment: i edited the code, check it now

Comment: Now, It's not playing any sound, here's my code https://ideone.com/tcNMet

Comment: add next() as last line inside your playtone() method